# PHP display data in table using loop

Tags: php, html, t-sql

- I have This Table in database

| id | TERM_CODE | COURSE_TITLE | COURSE_HOURS | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | 202210 | Calculus I | 3 | A |
| 555 | 202210 | Data Structure | 3 | A+ |
| 555 | 202220 | Calculus II | 3 | A |
| 555 | 202220 | Software Engineering | 3 | B |

- I Want to display data like this in php :

```
Transcript  
Id:555
TERM_CODE: 202210
```

| COURSE_TITLE | COURSE_HOURS | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Calculus I | 3 | A |
| Data Structure | 3 | A+ |

```
TERM_CODE: 202220
```

| COURSE_TITLE | COURSE_HOURS | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Calculus II | 3 | A |
| Software Engineering | 3 | B |

[image]

my code :

```
<?php 
echo'  <table class="tab"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1"  >';
      
include 'db_conf.php';
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
$tsql = "SELECT *FROM OPENQUERY (student, 'select * from INTEGRATION.TRANSCRIPT  where ID=555  ')ORDER BY TERM_DESC "; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['TERM_CODE']."</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
           
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>COURSE_TITLE</td>";
    echo "<td>COURSE_HOURS</td>";
    echo "<td>GRADE</td>";
          
    echo "</tr>";
          
    echo "<td>" .$row['COURSE_TITLE']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['COURSE_HOURS']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['GRADE']."</td>";
     
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried, please share your best effort with us (code). Read [ask]!

Comment: Is there a specific problem? What output do you get currently? Remember we cannot run your code. I notice that after `echo "</tr>";` you do not open a `<tr>` again before making a `<td>`, so that might be messing up your layout a bit.

Comment: You've got some html issues there. As @ADyson said you close a row but don't open a new one, and your first row has only one column, where your others have three, and that's not going to render well. Tell us what problem you've having. Does your query run, without a space between * and FROM?

Comment: Surely the table header should be before the loop, and the table row that shows the actual `$row` variables inside the loop? Perhaps you also need to close and open a new table when the TERM_CODE changes.